# Is it possible to implement with Django Restframework?

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I'm making API Server with DRF(DB is MySQL).

Now I made some system similar with facebook's like.

First, below is my Database Structure.

[user table]

- userkey(PK)
- username

[article table]

- articleNo(PK)
- userkey(FK to user)
- content

[like table]

- articleNo
- userkey(FK to user)

When user click the "Like" buttons, articleNo and User's key will be inserted into like table.
Currently, When I access to /article/, shows below result.

```
    {
    "articleNo": 1,
    "userkey": "22222",
    "content": "test1",
    "date": "2018-02-14T22:34:36.673805+09:00"
    },
    {
    "articleNo": 2,
    "userkey": "11111",
    "content": "test2",
    "date": "2018-02-15T22:34:36.673805+09:00"
    },
    ...
    ...
```

If like table has two row like this,

```
+-----------+---------+
| articleNo | userkey | 
+-----------+---------+
|         1 | 11111   |
|         1 | 22222   |
+-----------+---------+
```

It means that 11111 and 22222 user likes articleNo==1.
So When user access to /article?userkey=11111, What I would like instead as output is something like:

```
    {
    "articleNo": 1,
    "userkey": "22222",
    "content": "test1",
    "isLiked": "true", // add this line
    "date": "2018-02-14T22:34:36.673805+09:00"
    },
    {
    "articleNo": 2,
    "userkey": "11111",
    "content": "test2",
    "isLiked": "false", // add this line
    "date": "2018-02-15T22:34:36.673805+09:00"
    },
    ...
    ...
```

Is it possible to implement with DRF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done entirely on the ORM level, by using [Django 1.8 conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

Having the following model structure (some example values):

```
class User(models.Model):
    userkey = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Article(models.Model):
    articleNo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

class Like(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

To demonstrate how this works, I created some example data:

```
john = User.objects.create(userkey=1, username='John')
alice = User.objects.create(userkey=2, username='Alice')

john_article = Article.objects.create(articleNo=1, user=john, content='Hi, I am John!')
alice_article = Article.objects.create(articleNo=2, user=alice, content='Hi, I am John!')

alice_likes_john_article = Like.objects.create(user=alice, article=john_article)
alice_likes_her_article = Like.objects.create(user=alice, article=alice_article)
john_likes_his_article = Like.objects.create(user=john, article=john_article)
```

You could achieve what you want on the ORM level:

```
articles = Article.objects.all().annotate(
    like_count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(like__user=john, then=1),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField(),
        )
    ),
).annotate(
    likes=Case(
        When(like_count__gt=0, then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

(If somebody knows a simpler way than the above, I would be happy to learn as well)

Now every `Article` instance in the `articles` queryset will have two additional attributes: `likes_count` with the number of likes an article has received from John, and `likes`, a boolean, indicating if John likes it or not. Obviously you're interested in the latter.

Just override the `get_queryset()` method of your `Article` ViewSet, and then add an additional field to the Serializer of your `Article` class.

Also, you probably need to somehow pass the `user` instance (or the id) for the filter, but that can be done in various ways, including (for example) reading the query params inside the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: Thanks for very detail reply! Maybe I have to update Django version cuz mine is 1.16. I will try it later. Thanks!